# Subtract 2 L.I. vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $U,V,W$ are linearly independent vectors. Consider the following statements:

i. $U+V, V+W, W+U$ are linearly independent vectors

ii. $U + 3V, W + 3V$ are linearly independent vectors

iii. $U-V, V-W, W-U$ are linearly independent vectors

Which statements are true?

A. i. only

B. ii. only

C. i. and ii.

D. i. and iii.

E. None

The answer is C.

But I don't understand why if U+V are L.I., why isn't U-V also L.I.?

Comment: Try adding the three vectors in iii.

Comment: "U+V are L.I." is a meaningless statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U,V,W$ are linearly independent vectors:$c_1U+c_2V+c_3W=0 \Rightarrow c_1=c_2=c_3=0$
$$$$
$c_1'(U+V)+c_2'(V+W)+c_3'(W+U)=0 \Rightarrow (c_1'+c_3')U+(c_1'+c_2')V+(c_2'+c_3')W=0 \Rightarrow $ $$c_1'+c_3'=0 \Rightarrow c_1'=-c_3'$$ $$ c_1'+c_2'=0 \Rightarrow c_1'=-c_2'\Rightarrow -c_3'=-c_2' \Rightarrow c_2' =c_3'(*)$$ $$ c_2'+c_3'=0 \Rightarrow c_2'=-c_3'\overset{(*)}{\rightarrow}c_2'=c_3'=0, c_1'=0$$
so $U+V, V+W, W+U$ are also linearly independent.
$$$$
$c_1'(U-V)+c_2'(V-W)+c_3'(W-U)=0 \Rightarrow (c_1'-c_3')U+(c_2'-c_1')V+(c_3'-c_2')W=0 \Rightarrow $ $$c_1'-c_3' \Rightarrow c_1'=c_3'$$ $$c_2'-c_1' \Rightarrow c_2'=c_1'$$ $$c_3'-c_2' \Rightarrow c_1'=c_2'$$ So $c_1'=c_2'=c_3'=0$ is NOT the only solution, so $U-V,V-W,W-U$ are not linearly independent.